# c++ make nested tuple "plain" / "flatten"

Tags: c++, tuples

**Question** :
What is the best way to make tuple of tuples "plain"? E.g. one dimensional.

*Case1*

```
template <class Field>
auto process_field(Field&& field){
    // or another std::get<ids>(field)...
    return std::forward_as_tuple(field.fst, field.snd, field.thrd, field.fth); 
}

template <std::size_t ...ids, class Rec>
auto iterate_record(std::index_sequence<ids...>, Rec && rec){
    return forward_as_tuple(
        process_field
        (std::get<ids>( forward<Rec>(rec).data))...
    );
}
```

`iterate_record` returns tuple of tuples. I need plain tuple.

Maybe I need some kind of wrapper around `iterate_record`, or directly around this: `process_field (std::get<ids>( forward<Rec>(rec).data))...`

---

*Case2*

I have a tuple of tuples (concrete types, not references). How to copy it to plain version efficiently?

Comment: `tuple_cat` instead of `forward_as_tuple` in `iterate_record` ?

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Example, please?

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8519e2e1067385f9

Comment: Is it possible to use tuple_cat efficiently for depth >2 ?

Comment: if `process_field` returns a tuple of values (not references) you won't get away without a move (or a copy in worst case). otherwise you would have a  tuple of dangling references

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Agree for case1. But what about case2? - We already have nested tuple - need to make it completely plain. By just using tuple_cat we'll get n copies (where n=tuple_depth-1), instead of theoretically possible one.

Comment: You mean you have a tuple of tuples of tuples ?

Comment: tuple of tuples of tuples OR  tuple of tuples of tuples of tuple of tuples of tuples .... Consider I have depth >=2 (all elements have the same depth), need to make it depth = 1.

Comment: @tower120 ... just use `tuple_cat` *everywhere* you're using `forward_as_tuple` if `process_field()` is taking a `tuple` for `field`

Comment: @CoffeeandCode Good advice for procedural generated tuples. What if I have data stored in nested tuples and want to process it with function which works with simple, plain tuples?

Comment: The term you are looking for is probably "flatten" a tuple, i.e. make it flat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my take.

First, a wrapper, which is needed to properly handle tuples containing references and cv-qualification on the source tuple and the elements. We store 1) the type this wrapper should unwrap to; and 2) whether we can move from the source.

```
template<class U, class T, bool can_move>
struct wrapper {
    T* ptr;
    wrapper(T& t) : ptr(std::addressof(t)) {}

    using unwrapped_type = 
        std::conditional_t<can_move, 
                           std::conditional_t<std::is_lvalue_reference<U>{}, T&, T&&>, 
                           std::conditional_t<std::is_rvalue_reference<U>{}, T&&, T&>>;
    using tuple_element_type = U;

    unwrapped_type unwrap() const{
        return std::forward<unwrapped_type>(*ptr);
    }
};
```

Next, a function to unwrap a tuple of wrappers:

```
template<class... Wrappers, std::size_t... Is>
auto unwrap_tuple(const std::tuple<Wrappers...>& t, std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
    return std::tuple<typename Wrappers::tuple_element_type...>(std::get<Is>(t).unwrap()...);
}

template<class... Wrappers>
auto unwrap_tuple(const std::tuple<Wrappers...>& t) {
    return unwrap_tuple(t, std::index_sequence_for<Wrappers...>());
}
```

Now to transform a (possibly nested) tuple into a flattened tuple of wrappers. This is very similar to Piotr's `explode`:

```
template<bool can_move, class V, class T>
auto wrap_and_flatten(T& t, char){
    return std::make_tuple(wrapper<V, T, can_move>(t));
}
template<class T> struct is_tuple : std::false_type {};
template<class... Ts> struct is_tuple<std::tuple<Ts...>> : std::true_type {};
template<class T> struct is_tuple<const T> : is_tuple<T> {};
template<class T> struct is_tuple<volatile T> : is_tuple<T> {};

template<bool can_move, class, class Tuple,
         class = std::enable_if_t<is_tuple<std::decay_t<Tuple>>{}>>
auto wrap_and_flatten(Tuple& t, int);

template<bool can_move, class Tuple, std::size_t... Is>
auto wrap_and_flatten(Tuple& t, std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
    return std::tuple_cat(wrap_and_flatten<can_move, std::tuple_element_t<Is, std::remove_cv_t<Tuple>>>(std::get<Is>(t), 0)...);
}

template<bool can_move, class V, class Tuple, class>
auto wrap_and_flatten(Tuple& t, int) {
    using seq_type = std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<Tuple>{}>;
    return wrap_and_flatten<can_move>(t, seq_type());
}

template<class Tuple>
auto wrap_and_flatten_tuple(Tuple&& t){
    constexpr bool can_move = !std::is_lvalue_reference<Tuple>{};
    using seq_type = std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<std::decay_t<Tuple>>{}>;
    return wrap_and_flatten<can_move>(t, seq_type());
}
```

Finally, bringing it all together - wrap, flatten, and then unwrap:

```
template <typename T>
auto merge_tuple(T&& t)
{
    return unwrap_tuple(wrap_and_flatten_tuple(std::forward<T>(t)));
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c49a58c799484342).

Comment: Is it possible to get result with references to original, too? :) It seems very helpful.

Comment: @tower120 So all references and never values? Just use `unwrapped_type` instead of `tuple_element_type` in `unwrap_tuple`.

Comment: you see references very useful as "adapter" from nested to plain tuple, when you just need to pass it to function.... In other words, allow function which work with plain tuples (for example, find max/min value), to work with nested for free... So I need both :) Reference to original and copy from original.

Comment: I never saw `std::addressof` before, is it safe to use? Seems like it do `reinterpret_cast` inside, which, as I understand, have implementation defined behavior, so may be not portable.

Comment: @tower120 What [`std::addressof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/addressof) does is clear-cut: "Obtains the actual address of the object or function `arg`, even in presence of overloaded `operator&`". Whether it uses `reinterpret_cast`, a compiler intrinsic, or voodoo magic inside is irrelevant; it must behave as specified.

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <utility>
#include <tuple>
#include <cstddef>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
auto explode(T&& t, char)
{
    return std::forward_as_tuple(std::forward<T>(t));
}

template <typename T, std::size_t I = std::tuple_size<std::decay_t<T>>{}>
auto explode(T&& t, int);

template <typename T, std::size_t... Is>
auto explode(T&& t, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
{
    return std::tuple_cat(explode(std::get<Is>(std::forward<T>(t)), 0)...);
}

template <typename T, std::size_t I>
auto explode(T&& t, int)
{
    return explode(std::forward<T>(t), std::make_index_sequence<I>{});
}

template <typename T, std::size_t... Is>
auto decay_tuple(T&& t, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
{
    return std::make_tuple(std::get<Is>(std::forward<T>(t))...);
}

template <typename T>
auto decay_tuple(T&& t)
{
    return decay_tuple(std::forward<T>(t), std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<std::decay_t<T>>{}>{});
}

template <typename T, std::size_t... Is>
auto merge_tuple(T&& t, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
{
    return decay_tuple(std::tuple_cat(explode(std::get<Is>(std::forward<T>(t)), 0)...));
}

template <typename T>
auto merge_tuple(T&& t)
{
    return merge_tuple(std::forward<T>(t), std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<std::decay_t<T>>{}>{});
}
```

*Test:*

```
int main()
{
    std::tuple<
               std::tuple<
                          std::tuple<
                                     std::tuple<Noisy, Noisy>
                                    >
                         >
             , std::tuple<
                          std::tuple<Noisy>
                         >
              > t;        

    auto x = merge_tuple(t);

    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(x), std::tuple<Noisy, Noisy, Noisy>>{}, "!");
}
```

*Output:*

```
Noisy()
Noisy()
Noisy()
Noisy(const Noisy&)
Noisy(const Noisy&)
Noisy(const Noisy&)
~Noisy()
~Noisy()
~Noisy()
~Noisy()
~Noisy()
~Noisy()
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b54a8195cd1eb1e8)

Comment: Nice, but 1) `tuple_size` isn't necessarily SFINAE-friendly, and 2) does not work with tuples containing references?

Comment: Looks like an answer to my question. But... :) Why copy constructor called only once? You call `tuple_cat` multiple times.

Comment: @T.C. it work with everything - just remove/comment `decay_tuple` in `merge_tuple`. Look http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/664616268436454a . Without `decay_tuple` - tuple will contain references to original array (which is perfect for function calls, as for me) [it actually should store and then "restore" original state, instead just decay it]. So I think maybe here should be two functions - first for merging (with references, zero overhead), and second - for actually copying (with original types).

Comment: @tower120 neither preserves the original types. Given `std::tuple<Noisy&&, Noisy&, Noisy> t = /* ... */;`, `merge_tuple(t)` is not an identity transformation.

Comment: @T.C. I added `decay_tuple` on purpose to force a copy of all tuple elements, thinking this is what OP wants, and I didn't consider a tuple of references, I will have to take a look at this case